# Select Top 5 salary for each category

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I have a table similar to this one:

```
id   sml  desc amount
1     23   bla   100
2     23   bla   50
3     23   bla   30
4     23   bla   20
1     40   bla1  100
2     40   bla2  23
3     40   bla3  34
4     40   bla4  34
```

It is the result of several joins from other tables. I would like to select the five employees with the highest value in the `amount` column for each `sml` value.

Example output below: (my example doesn't have five of each `sml` so I'm using only displaying two. Also, if 5th and 6th values are equal I'd like to return both)

```
id   sml  desc amount
1     23   bla   100
2     23   bla   50
1     40   bla1  100
2     40   bla2  100
3     40   bla3  34
```

I tried the following query:

```
select [MS_EmployeeNumber],[SA_Semel],[Description],sum([MS_Amount]) as Amount,
rank() over (Partition BY [SA_Semel], [Description]

select [MS_EmployeeNumber],[SA_Semel],[Description],sum([MS_Amount]) as Amount,
rank() over (Partition BY [SA_Semel], [Description]
                ORDER BY sum([MS_Amount]) Desc) AS Rank
from [dbo].[MonthlySalary] as sml
inner join [dbo].[SmlAnalyse] as SA on SA.SA_Semel = sml.MS_Semel
inner join [dbo].[SalarySMLlist] as list on list.Semel = SA.SA_Semel
group by [MS_EmployeeNumber],[SA_Semel],[Description]
order by SA_Semel, Amount desc
```

When I run this the rank doing his job on the all table and consider my request to do the rank over MS_Semel.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Could you share the outout you'd want to get for this sample input please?

Comment: I didn't analyse your entire query. It seems that you already know how to use rank so just add your query as a subquery and an outer select with the where condition rank<=5

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating things with your query. `rank` (or rather `dense_rank`, according to the way you seem to be handling duplicates) already gives you the ranking per `sml`, now you just need to filter accordingly:

```
SELECT [id], [sml], [desc], [amount]
FROM   (SELECT [id], [sml], [desc], [amount], 
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [sml] ORDER BY [amount] DESC) rk
        FROM   [dbo].[MonthlySalary]) t
WHERE  rk <= 5
```

Comment: I think `rank()` is more appropriate than `dense_rank()`.  Consider the case where the values are 100,100,100,100,100,100,99,98,97,96.  I interpret the question as only wanting the 100s, not all of them.